# Virtual Keyboard does not appear while clicking on text field in Android after using iScroll.js plugin

Tags: android, scroll, touch, cordova, textfield

I am new to phonegap and jqTouch, I am using these for developing Android application.

The problem is, the touch event on textfields working fine on iPhone, but not working on Android, nothing happens when we tap on textfield.

Edit: I came to know that the problem is because the iScroll plugin is being used. When I remove this, the functionality works fine, but I need to use this in my application.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with iScroll and Android textfields?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What should it do when you tab on it? And how did you catch the event?

Comment: are you trying to prevent scrolling by calling preventDefault(); on the event object somewhere in your code?

Comment: I have seen problems with this sort of thing (even in gmail in the android browser) where the z-index does not work (android bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721) and some similar strange effects with the touch screen not registering touches on the correct element after scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the sort of problem you are talking about. When iScroll is being used on a page, it disables the input, select functionality within a form.

It is a known issue and there seem to be a few work arounds out there. Apparently, this is supposed to fix the issue without disabling the iScroll functionality:

In the touchStart function make sure to add the following condition:

```
if (e.target.tagName != "SELECT") 
{ 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     e.stopPropagation(); 
}
```